# Disable onChange event at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, my onChange event on my select input fires when the page load.

What I'm trying to do is have an onChange event occur when the user selects the first option of a select dropdown.  But since the first option is default, it is firing automatically.  I can't change the default as that is against what the client wants.  Is there a way to disable this? I'm not too familiar with how magento fires off javascript on page loads, since I think that's what the problem is.

This is mostly for my catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml page where I want something to happen (like an alert) when user clicks on the first option of the configurable product.

```
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());$_jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig();$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();?><?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
<dl>
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <?php
    $_rendered = false;
    foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
        $_renderer =       $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
        if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') &&     $_renderer->shouldRender($_attribute, $_jsonConfig)):
            $_renderer->setProduct($_product);
            $_renderer->setAttributeObj($_attribute);
            echo $_renderer->toHtml();
            $_rendered = true;
            break;
        endif;
    endforeach;

    if (!$_rendered):
    ?>
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" onChange="spConfig.getSelectedIndex()">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
              </select>
          </div>
    </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>

<?php if ($this->getLayout()->getBlock('size_chart')->getSizeChartVersion() > 0): ?>
    <span id="size-chart">Size Chart</span>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $_jsonConfig ?>);


    spConfig.getSelectedIndex = function(){
        for (var i = this.settings.length -1; i>=0; i--){

            if(this.settings[i].selectedIndex == 0)
            {
                alert('yes');
            }
        }
    }



</script>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Why can't you include your alert after the other nested action that occurs inside of the onChange?

Comment: @DavidLerner Code snippet is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use spconfig object. Replace your `catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` code with below. I have used the `onchange="spConfig.getSelectedIndex()"` onchange function.

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)): ?>
    <dl>
        <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
            <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
            <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast) { ?> class="last"<?php } ?>>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" onchange="spConfig.getSelectedIndex()">
                        <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);


spConfig.getSelectedIndex = function ()
{
    for (var i = this.settings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (this.settings[i].selectedIndex == 0)
        {
          alert('yes');  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, for some reason under the `if (selected.config)` statement, any code there does not execute when the selectedIndex is 0, which is for "choose an option"

Comment: yes, it will not go inside that condition if you select the "choose an option". Because for this option there is on any value set and if you inspect the code and check for this option value is set to blank and also in config array js has no value for this option.

Comment: I understand. However, My goal strictly depends on something happening when "choose an option" is selected.  Nothing should happen when other options are selected, only the "choose an option". Do you know how I can do that? Thanks

Comment: I want something to happen when users select "Choose an option" on change, but not when the page loads.  That is the problem that I wanted to solve from the beginning.  When the page loads, it already is on "choose an option", but should not do anything until users click back to it

Comment: edited my answer. see if that work for you..

Comment: The edited answer still becomes the original problem. I put an alert inside the if statement, and it goes off right when the page loads.  It should not go off when the page loads, only when user clicks on the option to go to "choose an option".  I mainly ask this because I have a bug with magento, and I want the page to refresh when users click on 'choose an option'.  Since it's happening on load, it would mean I will be auto-refreshing in a loop.

Comment: Edited again now check. It should work now.

Comment: Let me know if you have still issue. if you want it on just page load, remove onchange event onchange="spConfig.getSelectedIndex()"

Comment: Sorry, it still has the same problem.  The alert('yes') fires when the page loads

Comment: do you mean if user select the option "choose an option" alert should not come right?

Comment: I want the alert to come on only when user clicks on "choose an option", not when the page automatically loads to it. Sorry if this is confusing

Comment: What I want is: page loads, nothing happens. User selects an option (ex: red color), nothing happens. User selects "choose an option", then alert.

Comment: Ok I have deleted event window load from my script. when you first time open the product page alert will not come. if user select the any option that time also alert will not come. but if user again switch back to option "choose an option" alert will come. let me know if this is correct or anything need to change

Comment: Now it should work as edited my answer.

Comment: Please ctrl+f5 and check again.

Comment: The code is the same as your other edit.  When the page loads, alert('yes'), comes on.  It should not come on when the page loads.

Comment: Strange it should not. I am checking at my end and it is working fine. can you replace complete your configurable.phtml file with above entire code and refresh cache from admin also flush javascript cache.

Comment: I do not have cache enabled, but I flushed anyway.  Still does not work. Maybe I have more to my configurable.phtml I need to show you. Give me a few minutes to edit my post

Comment: I edited to include my entire configurable.phtml.  Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Not sure, are you working on live URL or in local server?

Comment: My local server.  If you go here (http://www.omcgear.com/mens/mens-clothing/men-s-jackets/marmot-gravity-jacket-men-s.html), Select small for size, then select cinder/dark granite(the only option).  Now you cannot go and change to selecting Large or Medium.  I want users to click on "choose an option" and I will have a page refresh with AJAX to start over. Do you see what I'm trying to do now? Very strange bug with my system when selecting configurables

Comment: I see you have already customized code for the options. Like customer can see both dropdown options and will not able to select only those options based on first dropdown value. You will need to debug that is the only option. My code will work for only default magento code.

Comment: Yeah, the javascript file is very large and taking a lot of time to figure out what's going on.  I wanted to do a quick fix(refreshing page on "choose an option"), but even that is not proving to be easy.  I want to thank you for all your help. It helped me learn a lot.  I'll mark your answer is correct, as others may find it correct if they didn't customize it like mines.  Thank you!

Comment: you welcome @nguyminh